# R, mutate and "Unsupported type NILSXP for column"

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a snapshot of my data:

```
  structure(list(CPUBID = c(1000001L, 1000002L, 1000003L, 10001L, 
1000201L, 1000203L, 10003L, 1000801L, 1000802L, 1000803L, 1001L, 
1001101L, 1001102L, 1001601L, 1002401L, 1002402L, 1002403L, 1002601L, 
1002602L, 1002604L), MPUBID = c(10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 100L, 
10002L, 10002L, 100L, 10008L, 10008L, 10008L, 10L, 10011L, 10011L, 
10016L, 10024L, 10024L, 10024L, 10026L, 10026L, 10026L), CYRB = c(1982L, 
1984L, 1988L, 1985L, 1986L, 1992L, 1993L, 1984L, 1986L, 1988L, 
1983L, 1987L, 1992L, 1977L, 1981L, 1984L, 1998L, 1980L, 1981L, 
1984L), twinfam = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SAMESEX = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), top25 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), top5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), quantity = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("CPUBID", "MPUBID", 
"CYRB", "twinfam", "SAMESEX", "top25", "top5", "quantity"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to use the twinfam(twin in family) and SAMESEX(first two born children same sex) binary variables to create a fourth variable that takes on 4 possible values:

- 1 if SAMESEX == 0 & twinfam == 0
- 2 if SAMESEX == 1 & twinfam == 0
- 3 if SAMESEX == 0 & twinfam ==1
- 4 if SAMESEX == 1 & twinfam ==1

After playing around a bit I tried using:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(both = for (i in 1:nrow(PIATmathreg6)) {
                              if(twinfam[i] == 0 & SAMESEX[i] == 0) both = 1
                              else if(twinfam[i] == 0 & SAMESEX[i] == 1) both = 2
                              else if(twinfam[i] == 1 & SAMESEX[i] == 0) both = 3
                              else both = 4})
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: Unsupported type NILSXP for column "both"
```

and can't seem to resolve this error. Any advice on why I get this error, and how it might be resolved, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to create a key/value dataset and do a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- data.frame(SAMESEX = c(0, 1, 0, 1), twinfam = c(0, 0, 1, 1), both = 1:4)
left_join(df, df2, by = c("SAMESEX", "twinfam"))
#    CPUBID MPUBID CYRB twinfam SAMESEX top25 top5 quantity both
#1  1000001  10000 1982       0       1     0    0        1    2
#2  1000002  10000 1984       0       1     0    0        1    2
#3  1000003  10000 1988       0       1     0    0        1    2
#4    10001    100 1985       0       1     0    0        1    2
#5  1000201  10002 1986       0       0     0    0        1    1
#6  1000203  10002 1992       0       0     1    0        1    1
#7    10003    100 1993       0       1     0    0        1    2
#8  1000801  10008 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
#9  1000802  10008 1986       0       0     0    0        1    1
#10 1000803  10008 1988       0       0     0    0        1    1
#11    1001     10 1983       0       1     1    0        0    2
#12 1001101  10011 1987       0       0     0    0        0    1
#13 1001102  10011 1992       0       0     0    0        0    1
#14 1001601  10016 1977       0       1     0    0        1    2
#15 1002401  10024 1981       0       0     1    0        1    1
#16 1002402  10024 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
#17 1002403  10024 1998       0       0     0    0        1    1
#18 1002601  10026 1980       0       0     0    0        1    1
#19 1002602  10026 1981       0       0     0    0        1    1
#20 1002604  10026 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use dplyr, you could try the following. Your data frame is called `mydf` here. You could use `case_when()` and create `both`. If I am not mistaken, you cannot use the function in `mutate()` yet. So, you want to create a vector and use `cbind()` in the end.

```
both <- case_when(mydf$SAMESEX == 0 & mydf$twinfam == 0 ~ 1,
                  mydf$SAMESEX == 1 & mydf$twinfam == 0 ~ 2,
                  mydf$SAMESEX == 0 & mydf$twinfam == 1 ~ 3,
                  mydf$SAMESEX == 1 & mydf$twinfam == 1 ~ 4)

cbind(mydf, both)
```

As akrun commented, now you can use `case_when()` in `mutate()`.

```
mydf %>%
mutate(both = case_when(.$SAMESEX == 0 & .$twinfam == 0 ~ 1,
                        .$SAMESEX == 1 & .$twinfam == 0 ~ 2,
                        .$SAMESEX == 0 & .$twinfam == 1 ~ 3,
                        .$SAMESEX == 1 & .$twinfam == 1 ~ 4))

#    CPUBID MPUBID CYRB twinfam SAMESEX top25 top5 quantity both
#1  1000001  10000 1982       0       1     0    0        1    2
#2  1000002  10000 1984       0       1     0    0        1    2
#3  1000003  10000 1988       0       1     0    0        1    2
#4    10001    100 1985       0       1     0    0        1    2
#5  1000201  10002 1986       0       0     0    0        1    1
#6  1000203  10002 1992       0       0     1    0        1    1
#7    10003    100 1993       0       1     0    0        1    2
#8  1000801  10008 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
#9  1000802  10008 1986       0       0     0    0        1    1
#10 1000803  10008 1988       0       0     0    0        1    1
#11    1001     10 1983       0       1     1    0        0    2
#12 1001101  10011 1987       0       0     0    0        0    1
#13 1001102  10011 1992       0       0     0    0        0    1
#14 1001601  10016 1977       0       1     0    0        1    2
#15 1002401  10024 1981       0       0     1    0        1    1
#16 1002402  10024 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
#17 1002403  10024 1998       0       0     0    0        1    1
#18 1002601  10026 1980       0       0     0    0        1    1
#19 1002602  10026 1981       0       0     0    0        1    1
#20 1002604  10026 1984       0       0     0    0        1    1
```

Comment: @akrun Long time no speak. Thanks for the information. My last update about `case_when()` was Hadley's post on R bloggers back in June. Now I know that the function is working in `mutate()`. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good to see you again.  Hope you are doing well.

Comment: @akrun I've been doing well. I just don't have time to commit myself here as I used to due to my job. But I'll be around here more in September since I have time for myself. By the way, `mydf %>% mutate(both = case_when(.$SAMESEX == 0 & .$twinfam == 0 ~ 1,...)` works. But `mutate(mydf, both = case_when(.$SAMESEX == 0 & .$twinfam == 0 ~ 1,...)` does not work. Do you happen to know why this is the case?

Comment: You are right.  It is not working.  I don't know the reason

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the confirmation. I'll send a message to Hadley and see what he says.

Comment: I think `case_when` is still in the initial stages.  It will change its behavior in the next version or so.

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I would say so too.